# Fill multiple columns per row

Tags: t-sql, etl

From a 3-party application I receive a data to import into tsql. There are four fields matching our fields in our database table. But the logic is different.
The 3-party app has no 'filling structure'. But we need to fill the fields from right to left with no gaps.

```sql
DECLARE @input TABLE ( field1 VARCHAR(60)
,                      field2 VARCHAR(60)
,                      field3 VARCHAR(60)
,                      field4 VARCHAR(60) )

/*Input Data from 3rd-party app*/
INSERT @input
VALUES ( 'row1field1', NULL,         NULL,         NULL         )
,      ( 'row2field1', 'row2field2', NULL,         NULL         )
,      ( 'row3field1', 'row3field2', 'row3field3', NULL         )
,      ( 'row4field1', 'row4field2', NULL,         'row4field4' )
```

Expected result should be:

```
|NULL|NULL      |NULL      |row1field1|
|NULL|NULL      |row2field1|row2field2|
|NULL|row3field1|row3field2|row3field3|
|NULL|row4field1|row4field2|row4field4|
```

I tried CASE to solve this, but of course there are to many combinations.
Or maybe use STRING_AGG and than split it again, but seams a bit strange to.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include an example of how the data from the 3rd party looks like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work assuming there is always a first column in the input and it has a unique value. If it isn't you'll need an extra initial step with another row_number to give you something unique as the row group.

We unpivot the columns, sequence them and then pivot them back up again in the desired order.

```
WITH FieldsUnpivoted AS
(
SELECT 
I.field1 AS RowGroup
,Fields.Field
,Fields.OrderNo
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY I.Field1 ORDER BY Fields.OrderNo DESC) AS FieldOrder
FROM @input AS I
CROSS APPLY 
    (VALUES 
         (I.field1,1)
        ,(I.field2,2)
        ,(I.field3,3)
        ,(I.field4,4)
    ) AS Fields(Field,OrderNo)
WHERE Fields.Field IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT 
RowGroup
,MIN(CASE WHEN FieldOrder = 4 THEN Field ELSE NULL END) AS Field1 
,MIN(CASE WHEN FieldOrder = 3 THEN Field ELSE NULL END) AS Field1 
,MIN(CASE WHEN FieldOrder = 2 THEN Field ELSE NULL END) AS Field1 
,MIN(CASE WHEN FieldOrder = 1 THEN Field ELSE NULL END) AS Field1 
FROM FieldsUnpivoted
GROUP BY RowGroup
```